# Как работают args и kwargs вместе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, параметры, аргументы

Есть функция:

```
def a(q, w=5, *args, **kwargs):
    print(q)
    print(w)
    print(args)
    print(kwarks)
```

вызываем функцию:

`a(1,2,3,4,{1:2})`

в `q` попадет **`1`**, в `w` попадет **`5`**, в `args` попадет все остальное.

Есть ли смысл в одну функцию помещать и аргзы и кваргзы? 
Ведь в любом случае аргзы съедают все оставшиеся переменные.

Comment: потому что нет ни одного именованого. Укажите (1,2,3,4,{1:2},z=5). И z'ка прилетит в kwargs. Смысл использования, конечно же, есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Используйте общепринятые конструкции *args и **kwargs для захвата позиционных и именованных аргументов.
- Конструкцию **kwargs нельзя располагать до *args. Если это сделать — будет выдано сообщение об ошибке.
- Остерегайтесь конфликтов между именованными параметрами и **kwargs, в случаях, когда значение планируется передать как **kwarg-аргумент, но имя ключа этого значения совпадает с именем именованного параметра.
- Оператор *можно использовать не только в объявлениях функций, но и при их вызове.

---

```
#def a(q, w=5, *args, **kwargs):
def a(q, *args, w=5, **kwargs):
    print(f'args   = {args}')
    print(f'kwargs = {kwargs}\n')
    print(f'q   = {q}')
    print(f'w   = {w}')

    
a(1, 2, 3, 4, {1:2}, hello='world')
```