# Режимы сопоставления аргументов функции в python. Использование *args и **kwargs

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно использовать *args и **kwargs в python.
Вопросы следующие:
Если имеется функция, в которой имеются позиционные аргументы и *args

```
def function(first, second, *args):
```

то как мне правильно вызвать её в том случае, если я хочу их присваивать как именованные:

```
function(234, first=123, second=444)
```

В данном случае я хочу задать аргументы указывая какой есть какой, но в таком случае при попытке прописать остальные данные в *args получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: function() got multiple values for argument 'first'
```

Как правильно совместить использование *args  и именованных аргументов на подобном примере, возможно ли это.

Например я хочу задать

```
def function(first, second, *args, **kwargs):
```

В таком случае, могу ли я использовать что-то подобное?

```
function(234, first=123, second=444, third=3)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работают args и kwargs вместе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335384/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-args-%d0%b8-kwargs-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: К сожалению вопрос не тот-же самый. Перед созданием вопроса я видел этот пост. Но спасибо.

Comment: На вторую часть вопроса он частично отвечает. Но вопрос был ещё и в том, что если я указываю позиционный аргумент, а в вызове функции хочу указать ему его параметр, то как это сделать, если я хочу использовать *args

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правила перечисления аргументов в вызове функции таковы:

1. позиционные аргументы, идущие друг за другом;
2. *args - итерируемая последовательность позиционых аргументов;
3. ключевые аргументы (значения по умолчанию);
4. **kwargs - словарь ключевых аргументов.

Соответственно, если вы используете:
`def function(first, second, *args, **kwargs):`,
то сначала у вас должны идти позиционные агрументы first и second.
Компилятор совершенно правильно сообщает вам, что в варианте
`function(234, first=123, second=444, third=3)` у вас два параметра (234 и 123) на один аргумент first.
Более того, даже я, будучи человеком, не могу понять, что такое параметр 234 тут? Он не подпадает под описанные вами аргументы. Если это *args, то при таком описании, как выше, правильно вызывать:
`function(123, 444, 3, 234)`

Пример:

```
def function(first, second, *args):
    print ('first:', first, 'second:', second, '*args', args)

function(123, 444, 3, 234) # Печатает: first: 123 second: 444 *args: (3, 234)
```

Аналогично и для `def function(first, second, *args, **kwargs):`.

Возможно, вы несколько путаете параметры и аргументы. Например, обратите внимание, что ваш вопрос ниже просто противоречив. Вы говорите про "именованные аргументы", но далее в определении функции никакие именованные аргументы вы не указываете, у вас сразу за *args идут **kwargs:

*Начало цитаты:*

"Как правильно совместить использование *args и именованных аргументов на подобном примере, возможно ли это.

Например я хочу задать

`def function(first, second, *args, **kwargs):`"

*Конец цитаты.*

Рекомендую почитать учебник Чернышова "Основы программирования на Python":
3.2.1. "Значения аргументов по умолчанию",
3.2.2. "Режимы сопоставления аргументов функции".

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос был в том, можно ли указывать через равно first=123, second=444 в подобном примере

Comment: Можно. Но на своем месте.

Comment: Спасибо. По сути это и есть ответ на весь вопрос)

Comment: То есть вопрос "можно ли указывать через равно first=123, second=444 в подобном примере" вы сформулировали как: "Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно использовать *args и **kwargs в python?":-)) Советую точнее формулировать тогда:-)

Comment: Так или иначе мне дали более чем исчерпывающий ответ по всем вопросам)